# Butterknife @InjectView issue after updating to 7

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I'm using `@InjectView` for many of my views. After I updated to the newest version 7 they stopped working? What happened?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are experiencing this because Butterknife version 7 has a new set of naming conventions. You'll need to update your code to use the latest annotations.

Change `@InjectView` to `@Bind`.

Also change your Java code from `Butterknife.inject();` to `Butterknife.bind(this)`. I'm assuming you're doing this in an Activity. If you're doing this in a fragment or have more complicated use scenarios, you should check out the Butterknife documentation [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: And now in [v8 "@Bind becomes @BindView and @BindViews"](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2016-04-25)